# get nearby locations of certain location with mongoid or rubygeocode

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, geolocation, mongoid

I have something like

```
@office = Office.first
@offices = Office.where(:status => "active")
```

How do I get offices near @office from above variables,
   i.e I want something like

```
@offices.near(@office.latitude, @office.longitude) or
Office.near([@office.latitude, @office.longitude]).where(:status=>"active")
```

I can get this with @office.nearbys( with rubygeocoder) but that is not an option for me right now, I need to utilize a near method on the collection to get offices near a given office.

Or is there other gems I can use to do this if not possible with rubygeocoder or mongoid ? 
Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to find other solution but at last I am going with

```
@offices = @office.nearbys
```

At it does the work evenif not the way I wanted it to .